# Greatest Small date

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, algorithm, binary-search

I have a two date columns let's say A and B in two separate tables. A contains the information of the date of test and column B contains date at which the factory was calibrated. I want to extract information of how many days has been passed since the factory was last calibrated.

For example:

```
A=['2020-02-26', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29']

B=['2020-02-24', '2020-02-28']
```

`Days_Passed` since last calibration corresponding to `A` are `[2,3,0,1]`

Comment: Adapt merging the columns in O(n), keeping a pointer for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Take the smallest date as reference 0 and convert other dates into days with respect to 0(smallest date)

A = [2,3,4,5]

B = [0,4]

for each value of A, ***perform a binary search to find the nearest smallest or equal value in B...*** Their subtraction will be the Days_Passed since the last calibration.

Answer Array = [2,3,0,1].

Comment: My columns are pandas columns. Could you please help in pandas implementation?

Comment: You could easily convert pandas columns into lists.

Answer (score 0):

if dates in `A` and `B` be **in order**, this could be done in `O(n+m)` where `n` and `m` are the length of `A` and `B`. though you didn't mention about the programming language, this is the implementation in C#

the main part:

```
foreach (var testedDate in testedDates)
{
    if (nextCalibratedDate.HasValue && (testedDate - nextCalibratedDate.Value).Days >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((testedDate - nextCalibratedDate.Value).Days);
        calibratedDate = nextCalibratedDate.Value;
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            nextCalibratedDate = (DateTime?)enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine((testedDate - calibratedDate).Days);
    }
}
```

and this is the complete code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] A = new[] { "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-28", "2020-02-29" };
    string[] B = new[] { "2020-02-24", "2020-02-28" };

    var testedDates = A
        .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x))
        .ToArray();
    var calibratedDates = B
        .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x))
        .ToArray();

    var enumerator = calibratedDates.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    var calibratedDate = (DateTime)enumerator.Current;
    DateTime? nextCalibratedDate = default;
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        nextCalibratedDate = (DateTime?)enumerator.Current;
    }

    foreach (var testedDate in testedDates)
    {
        if (nextCalibratedDate.HasValue && (testedDate - nextCalibratedDate.Value).Days >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((testedDate - nextCalibratedDate.Value).Days);
            calibratedDate = nextCalibratedDate.Value;
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                nextCalibratedDate = (DateTime?)enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine((testedDate - calibratedDate).Days);
        }
    }
}
```